# SSIS Execution error concerning unicode and non-unicode types

Tags: unicode, deployment, error-handling, ssis

I am getting a strange error when execution my SSIS package into our Stage Enviroment. I did a filesystem deployment and scheduled it on a SQL Agent job

The error I receive is

> Columns "PGL_EMP_ID" and "EMP_ID" cannot convert between unicode and non-unicode string data types.(This is happening in the preexecute phase for a OLEDB command where EMP_ID is a variable of VARCHAR2 (oracle data type) and PGL_EMP_ID is DT_WSTR string datatype being populated into EMP_ID)

I have used Data Conversion and converted PGL_EMP_ID to Unicode (DT_WSTR) and the package is running without error from BIDS in Dev. I have also set `ValidateExternalMetadata` to false also for the OLE DB command. The Delay package validation is also set to true.

I am using XML and SQL Server Package configuration.

I think this is due to the Oracle driver mismatch: Dev has (11.2.0.3) and Stage has (11.2.0.1) versions

Comment: Think this is due to the oracle driver mismatch dev has (11.2.0.3) and stage has (11.2.0.1) versions.

Comment: This isn't a deployment error.   It's a run-time error.

Comment: @Srimant quite possible. I saw a similar issue with MySQL drivers interpreting data types as unicode/non-unicode varying between point releases